# Creating a class instance as a member of another class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Why does the following code not work? I get error C2059 'constant'. Using Visual C++ 2008.

```
class C {
public:
    C(int arg) {}
};

class B {
public:
    C c(1); //error C2059
    B() {}
};
```

I can't define a default constructor. Also I can't declare a pointer to C and then "new it" in B's constructor.

Comment: _"I see absolutely nothing wrong with my code."_ Which learning resource taught you to initialise members inside the class definition like that?

Comment: Well I don't see why you had to remove the sentence.

Comment: It was completely pointless and did not add to the question. It was just a statement of "my code must be right, I see absolutely nothing wrong in what I'm doing" so, what, it's someone else's fault? The compiler is broken? The language is not designed with _you_ in mind? Clearly you made an error and your little "nothing's wrong" doesn't change that.

Comment: Visual Studio has been known to have parsing bugs, such as this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/113118. So I was obviously alluding to a possible VS bug. I guess it was too subtle for you.

Comment: Funny how, after all that, there was a trivially obvious problem with your code. Try to assume _you_ made the mistake before blaming your tools.

Comment: It's obviously NOT a trivially obvious problem with my code when you consider that what I was trying to accomplish has been made possible in C++11, as another responder pointed out. Evidently someone else thinks that C++ should be enabled to do this. When you look at it that way, the problem lies in a limitation of C++98, more so than in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`C c()` is being interpreted as a function declaration, and the int literal `1` by itself makes the syntax invalid. Consider using braces instead (C++11) or direct initialization:

```
C c{1};
```

or:

```
B() : c(1) {}
```

§ 8.5

> 11 An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e.,
>   `()`, shall be value-initialized.
>
> [ Note: Since `()` is not permitted
>   by the syntax for *initializer*,
>
> `X a();`
>
> is not the declaration of an
>   object of class `X`, but the declaration of a function taking no
>   argument and returning an X. The form `()` is permitted in certain
>   other initialization contexts (5.3.4, 5.2.3, 12.6.2). — end note ]

Comment: C c{1}; gives me compiler error C2473 'c' looks like a function definition but there is no parameter list.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do what I think you're trying to do is with a [member initialiser list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list):

```
class B {
public:
    C c;
    B() : c(1) {}
};
```